# Server 2022 Domain, awful performance

Tags: windows-server-2022

I am a little at a loss here. Setting up new domains for a number of operations and first time I start the installation with Windows Server 2022 fresh. Let's talk of a baseline Domain here - 3 dc's (dc0, dc1, dc2). There are no obvious warnings (dcdiag included).

I start the desktop on dc2 and add dc0 and dc1 to the DNS manager - note that at this point nothing is not microsoft, it all is a clear single vendor setup.

Opening the context menu:

dc3 (where the desktop is running) DNS: fast.
dc1 or dc1: takes like 10 seconds to open.

These are the only machiens on the LAN. They run on a virtualization platform that  is essentialy empty right now. They are a fresh install with fresh patches and can reach the internet. Event logs are clean. it seems something is blocking, but I have no idea what. Ipv4 connectivity works, ipv6 is installed and active and not reaching the internet (no uplink) but it should not time out as there is no default route that blackholes. What causes this delay?

dcdiag is green, secure channel test is green.

not sure this IS related, but on another domain I have a SQL Server 2022 running and connecting to it from my desktop with SSMS takes way longer than 15 seconds. Some other tool (with lower timeout) complains about timeout during handshake. It seems and feels like the same issue - but again, no idea what is blocking here.

Update:
As per comment I was told to try disabling the firewall. THAT solved the issue (though is not a solution). So, the question runs down which setting in the firewall (standard Windows server install + then domain setup/join) is resulting in this being so slow.

Update: I have nailed it down to a number of rules that are not enabled, which is the trio of "Remote Service Management". Not that on the machines in server manager one can see "Remote Management" as enabled. If I enable those rules, the delay in the DNS management disappears.

Comment: Could be a DNS issue.... are all servers using the correct DNS servers? Is DNS working properly?

Comment: Given in my example all 3 server are the DC's - which by definition and standard user their local DNS - that is not an issue. Also I checked with external name resolution and that is - on all 3 machines - as fast as local resolution, and in general fast (as in: sub second) - if that is a DNS timeout, it comes from nowhere I Can see.

Comment: A newb question from me; I guess you use vmware ? Does you put the vm with the vmxnet3 or you left the e1000 that is usually by default (with the latest vm tool drivers) ? Remove too the QoS from the NIC, Windows tend to keep 80% of the bandwidth to itself.

Comment: I know this is bad practice, but first thing first I'd try to turn off Windows Firewall and see if something changes.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Fror a question ASK A QUESTION. DO not abuse other questions. And rtealize your question is so off here (as it shows zero competence) that it is not even funny - i.e. Windows is NOT keeping 80% of the bandwidth, but it may have a performance issue due to the way the e1000 is done, ages ago, which is extremely inefficient. Did you not learn that?

Comment: @Massimo I really do not care about firewall - this is actually a real domain setup JUST for this, totally throw away. The benefit of virtualization. Let me try ;) That would point to some optional service having a problem in the default setup (because the firewall is standard, and optional because a NEEDED service would not result in slow, but in timeout).

Comment: @TomTom I know, let talk more direct then. When you create a new VM vmware still use e1000 by default and the Win2022 server windowsupdate use it own pilot for the vmxnet3. I guess you didnt used the default here (used correct nic) and got the latest vmtool from vmware for the vmxnet, not microsoft ?

Comment: @TomTom and for the QoS settings I was vague, but you know such console use winrm to talk between server, and winrm got quota and such ?  removing the QoS can help identify your trouble.

Comment: Ok, QOS is out but WTF - disabling the internal firewall resulted in fast response.. Any idea how to find out what is wrong here? Note: This is so far a standard firewall, nothing is blocekd that was not blocked by the windows / domain install.

Comment: Windows firewall is like you told stupid, but it got different rule for IPv4 vs IPv6, can it be a timeout on a protocol and it failback to the other after, thus causing your delay? You could confirm with a wireshark.

Comment: Yeah, my problem with that is that those are pristine windows servers. Translate this into "installed from a source, patched, domain, domain controller installed" - no third party, no complex playing around. This would indicate some issue somewhere in the windows standard setup. If it is the firewall - then the firewall is badly configured out of the box. Definitely looks like a fallback.

Comment: @TomTom `If it is the firewall - then the firewall is badly configured out of the box`. There is a reason why people loathe Windows Firewall so much... and why it was my first suspect (yes, even before ruling out DNS).

Comment: Point is, I never had that problem with earlier versions. Last time I did set up a domain was with 2016 - and then updated it obviously - and there I never had this problem. Setting up this weekend a complete isolated test environment - this is awful.

Comment: @Massimo See my 2nd update - it seems that for some reason 3 firewall rules were not enabled, although remote management in server manager is shown as enabled. Any idea where this comes from? If you want you can formulate your comment and my update into an answer and I accept it.

Comment: @TomTom I don't really know, and probably I don't *want* to know. My first action after installing Windows is turning Windows Firewall off. I really think (as a 20-years experienced sysadmin) it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: (Also, why even bother with a local firewall? If you are in a LAN, it's useless. If you are exposed to the Internet, you should have a proper firewall.)

Comment: I would always recommend to manage the dns to starting the mmc console by doing it on the server where it's running, and choose one server to manage it on. Doing it using Remote Service Management could create a security risk when it's not properly setup and secured. In an AD domain you don't need to manage the dns on three server, because it replicated just like the ad database

Comment: I read a bit on that subject today, I will write a small answer if someday someone want to bypass the problem and use another method, I will let Massimo write the real answer

Comment: And please also run dcdiag on your domain controller to see if your domain is correctly working and dns is an good state

Comment: @yagmoth555 thanks but I don't think "turn off Windows Firewall" is a proper answer. I hate it so much I never properly investigated its configuration, I just prefer to get rid of it (of course disabling the *firewall* itself, not the Windows Firewall *service*, as some misguided people used to do).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Windows 2022 didn't created the corresponding IPv6's firewall rules for management service. Thus it created a situation where the mmc's console had to fallback to a supported protocol.

If someday someone fall into that problem and you need the firewall enabled, as it can appear on other service, the problem can arise as it's the OS that priorize IPv6 vs IPv4 if a host got both entry registered into the DNS (IPv4 and IPv6).

If you don't use in production IPv6;

- An easy fix could be to delete the IPv6 entry from the DNS if you don't use IPv6 in production.
- If you can't, or don't want to remove the IPv6 entry from the DNS, there is a registry key to make it priorize IPv4 over IPv6 (it does not deactivate IPv6, deactivating IPv6 is not recommended);

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters

KEY: DisabledComponents

That key got multiple value possible, but the one interesting is;

[image]

[image]

Some reference; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows

Comment: Bad advice. There is no real evidence that there is an issue in the ip stack, so then you don't need to change it.

Comment: @Ace what you talk about ? The OP found the issue as it’s a firewall rule that wasnt on. Did you read the conment section before commenting ? My answer was WHY it poke IPv6 before IPv4, as the missing rule was on the IPv6 section.

Comment: Your answer make no sense that is what im saying. I didn't realize that this answer was from before the op found the issue

Comment: @Ace No, its after… I leave another user make the answer. I left that answer as I found today why the frigging mmc use the IPv6 before IPv4, and as its a Q/A site I left the info to other

Comment: And it shouldn't be a problem that it looks like IPV6 is being used because in windows it's converted to IPV4 automatically, when needed

Answer (score 0):

You could create a group policy to allow Remote Service Management in the windows firewall on all three servers,and make sure to set a restriction on the rule that it's only allowed from the ip or subnet from the server you are managing the DNS from. Never disable the windows firewall that could create problems than you could think off

Comment: You should never disable the Windows Firewall *service* (as some misguided people used to do). It's perfectly fine to turn Windows Firewall off using its configuration or a GPO.